# Is it possible to prevent creation of new consumer groups by kafka clients?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to prevent kafka clients from creating their own consumer groups and instead join one of the existing consumer groups. Is it possible to enforce this through kafka ACL?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no direct API/command to prevent the kafka consumers to create new consumer groups.  If you want to let your consumer join existing group, you should mention the group name.

That's the whole idea that mutiple consumers should be able to consume from the same topic but with a different consumer group ID.

If you still want to do this, you need to add custom logic. First you should iterate the consumer groups and extract the existing consumer group name for that topic, and pass into your next consumers.